# having trouble walking into subdirectories

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, filesystems, c++-tr2

To familiarize myself with `<filesystem>`, I wrote a simple recursive function that walks a directory tree:

```
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::tr2::sys;
const fs::directory_iterator fs_end;

void walk(fs::path root)
{
    std::cout << "ENTERING " << root << '\n';
    for (auto it = fs::directory_iterator(root); it != fs_end; ++it)
    {
        if (is_directory(it->status()))
        {
            walk(it->path());
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << it->path() << " is not a directory\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "LEAVING " << root << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    walk("d:/a");
}
```

Unfortunately, this will only visit the immediate directories inside the directory specified in `main`. The subdirectories are not visited. To illustrate, I made a very simple directory structure:

[image: abcd]

The output of the program is as follows:

```
ENTERING d:/a
ENTERING b
LEAVING b
ENTERING c
LEAVING c
LEAVING d:/a
```

As you can see, d is not visited. Apparently, the for loop is run zero times inside c. Why?

Comment: Were you aware of [`recursive_directory_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tr2_proposal.html#Class-template-basic_recursive_directory_iterator) in the proposal and seeking to re-implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output it looks like `it->path()` is giving you the relative path, not the absolute path. While iterating, your *current directory* does not change, so trying to iterate over a directory with path 'b' or 'c' won't work and no subdirectories will be found in that non-existent directory. In your for-loop, try the following recursive call:

```
walk(root/it->path());
```

Now, when your program examines directory c, it should output:

```
ENTERING d:/a/c 
ENTERING d:/a/c/d
etc...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :) Is there an alternative way to get the absolute path from `it->path()` without manually prepending the root, by calling a member function on the path or something? Or is `it->path()` just a wrapper around the string "c" and does not have enough information do reconstruct the absolute path by itself?

Comment: @FredOverflow: I can't give you a definitive answer on that, I'm by no means an expert on this, but yes, in my experience path objects are convenient data structures to hold path strings and they are completely separate from the actual filesystem. It is the other functions of the filesystem library that give meanings to paths.
What actually surprised me is that the `directory_entry::path` member does not give an absolute path, because a directory iterator _is_ actually associated with an entity on the actual file system.